# vector addElement seems to be overwriting objects with same info

Tags: java, vector

Im confused with the behaviour of some code im working on. I can paste the whole code here as this is an assignment but am asking for possible ideas as to why this might be happening.

basically I have a Scanner object created that takes input for details - a number, first and last name - once I have those details I create a new object using the Person class which adds it into a vector (people) I declared beforehand: i use this code to create and add at same time:

```
people.addElement(new Person(number,firstName,familyName));
```

this works fine , in that it adds the object to the vector correctly but the problem arises when the program loops back again and starts the process over. The user is asked if they want to enter another person , if they say yes they go through the process of entering the data again and it shoudl create a new object with the next persons details and place it in the next index of the array BUT it seems to overwrite the previous details with the new one AND create a new object with the new details - i.e. leaving me with 2 or 3 or 4 *however many I input until I exit) objects stored in the vector all with EXACTLY the same details.

Ive checked what is stored in the vector by using a for loop to print them out at the end and I double checked in case it was a problem with my for loop , by putting manual print statement referencing each index directly (im sure it was correct as when I try to the first  3 indexes out but only enter two into the program I get an exception for it being out of bounds)

Hope that makes sense and that someone might have an idea as to why it might be behaving this way that I can look into. Like I say this is an assignment , so Im looking for direction rather than someone giving me the out and out answer please.

Comment: Post your Person class. My bet is that you've declares all its fields `static`.

Comment: JB Nizet - your absolutely correct. I had declared them all static and  have just changed that and tried and now it works again. thanks. I was  working on this last night and forgot I did that (and cant remember why either). Makes perfect sense. thankyou